# Codenameone: Android Build Failed with strange exception

Tags: codenameone

Since today (28.03.) the build of my app (CN1 build server) throws an build Exception which I don't understand. The Build yesterday worked without an error. The error from the error-log:

```
Dex: The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$8.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:565)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:276)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:574)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug FAILED
:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.334 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Can anybody help me to understand what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error is:

```
Dex: The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
```

In this case, add the build hint:
`android.multidex=true`

As written in the developer guide ([link](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html)):

> android.multidex -> Boolean true/false defaults to false. Multidex
>   allows Android binaries to reference more than 65536 methods. This
>   slows builds a bit so we have it off by default but if you get a build
>   error mentioning this limit you should turn this on.

Comment: Thank you - this build hint solves the problem. Never thought, that the number of method  references could be limited nowadays...